# Consistency in apparently trivial panel regression

Tags: panel-data, least-squares, consistency

I have the following model (from theory):

$$ y_{ij} = \beta x_{i} + e_{ij} $$

where $y_{ij}$ and $x_{i}$ are observed, $i$ is individual and $j$ is occupation, **and there is no constant**.

Is $E(e_{ij}|x_{i})=E(e_{ij})$ the **only** condition required for consistency of Pooled OLS?

Comment: Weak exogeneity is what you've written there and for OLS that will be sufficient for consistency. But I don't think the constant not being there matters?

Comment: I believe you also need the model to be correctly specified.

Comment: But according to Wooldridge (2010), page 56, a constant is needed for consistency. But, **if my model does not include a constant**, then what is the matter? I know I can trivially add a constant. But then how do I interpret the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consistency of OLS requires $E(x_iu_i) =0$ i.e. that the regressors are orthogonal to the contemporaneous error term. This can be assumed directly,  and it does not require or imply that the regressor matrix contains a constant nor that the error term has zero mean.

The tricky situation is that *if* we start by assuming that $E(u_i\mid x_i)= E(u_i) $ i.e.that the error term is "mean-independent" from the regressors, then we have

$$E(x_iu_i) = E[E(x_iu_i\mid x_i)] = E[x_iE(u_i\mid x_i)] = E[x_iE(u_i)]=E(x_i)E(u_i)$$

In order to have this equal to zero we either need to
1) Require that $E(u_i) = 0$, which can be guaranteed if a constant is included in the regressors
 or
2) Require that $E(x_i) = 0$ which can be achieved by centering the regressors around their mean.

Comment: Nice. Am I right to say that points 1) and 2) they are actually equivalent? This is because adding a constant is in effect "demeaning" the coefficient $\beta$?

Comment: @luchonacho Adding a constant demeans _the error term_, not the coefficient vector.